# compare list file with multiple similar files and generate matching records into single file

Tags: unix

i have list of products in search.txt and i need to find out the list of product records available in  multiple similar product files r files and generate  one consolidated file with matching products using unix.

search.txt:

```
B0003
A0024
B1545
```

product1.txt

```
00|01|20200403|123400
45|1|A0001|one
45|2|A0001|C001|001|003
45|2|B0003|C896|001|004
45|2|A0024|C234|001|004
45|1|B1542|two
45|2|B1542|C231|001|004
45|2|B1545|C237|001|004
90|0000001|
```

product2.txt

```
00|01|20200403|123400
45|1|A0002|one
45|2|A0002|C001|001|003
45|2|B0003|C896|001|004
45|2|A0024|C234|001|004
45|1|B1542|two
45|2|B1542|C231|001|004
45|2|B1545|C237|001|004
45|1|B777|two
45|2|B777|C231|001|004
45|2|B777|C237|001|004
90|0000001|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have multiple different formats for records in the same file, and don't have your expected results, so this is a best guess as to what you want, using `join` and `sort`:

```
$ join -11 -23 -t'|' -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6 <(sort search.txt) <(sort -t'|' -k3,3 product*.txt)
45|2|A0024|C234|001|004
45|2|A0024|C234|001|004
45|2|B0003|C896|001|004
45|2|B0003|C896|001|004
45|2|B1545|C237|001|004
45|2|B1545|C237|001|004
```

Another possible approach uses `grep`:

```
$ grep -Fhf <(sed 's/.*/|&|/' search.txt) product*.txt
45|2|B0003|C896|001|004
45|2|A0024|C234|001|004
45|2|B1545|C237|001|004
45|2|B0003|C896|001|004
45|2|A0024|C234|001|004
45|2|B1545|C237|001|004
```

---

Both of these require a shell like `bash` or `zsh` that understands `<(command)`  redirection syntax.

If doing a lot of stuff with these files, consider importing them into a database (sqlite3 is easiest). Queries with appropriate indexes will be a lot faster than scanning text files all the time.

Comment: Second might  work, i need only matching records with product file name for record type 45 and 2 with column 3 and 4 values: Ex: 
product1.txt,B0003,C234
product1.txt,A0024,C234
product1.txt,B1545,C237
product2.txt,B0003,C896
product2.txt,A0024,C234
product2.txt,B1545,C237

Comment: if possible please explain the grep with options so that i will understand fully

Answer (score 0):

Create a consolidated file with all the products in a single file

```
cat product*.txt > consolidated_product.txt
   while read line;
   do
   array=`echo ${line} | sed 's/\s/\n/g'`;
   for i in ${array};
   do
   echo "$i"; #replace this echo with grep  
   #grep $i consolidated_product.txt
   done;
   done <search.txt
```

This output can be redirected to another file.

Comment: actually each product file contains millions of records and i have 10 files so  consolidation_product.txt is hanged and taking more time

Comment: If that is the case, you can run on loop through the products.txt and for each of the products.txt, run your grep command.